# Get lowest sale from week of sales

Tags: java

My assignment asks me to get sales for 8 weeks, get the highest week sale and and lowest week sales. Although I can't figure out how to get the lowest week and values. I'm very new to Java

Here is my code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        int totalSales = 0;
        int averageSales = 0;
        int highestSale = 0;
        int highestWeek = 0;
        int lowestSale = 0;
        int lowestWeek = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

           int s = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Week " + (i+1) + ":"));

           totalSales += s;

           if(s > highestSale) {

                highestSale = s;
                highestWeek = i + 1;

            }
           if(lowestSale < s) {

                lowestSale = s;
                lowestWeek = i + 1;

            }
           }

          averageSales += totalSales / 8;

           String msg = "Total sales: £" + totalSales + "\n";
           msg += "Average sales: £" + averageSales + "\n";
           msg += "Highest week was " + highestWeek + ", sold £" + highestSale + "\n";
           msg += "Lowest week was " + lowestWeek + ", sold £" + lowestSale;

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);

        }
```

Comment: What is your question and where is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(lowestSale < s) {
    lowestSale = s;
    lowestWeek = i + 1;
  }
```

This should be this instead:

```
if(s < lowestSale) {
     lowestSale = s;
     lowestWeek = i + 1;
 }
```